# CUBLAS Sgemm confusing results

Tags: cuda, blas, cublas

For two matrices X and Q of size 4x3 and 2x3
which in memory look like

```
x = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]
q = [3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

I tried to use cublas multiplication cublasSgemm, but I couldn't manage to get expected results.

Since they are stored in row-major order so they should be interpreted as 3x4 and 3x2 so it seemed for me that

```
cublasSgemm(cublas_handle,
    CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N,
    q_rows_num, x_rows_num, dim,
    &alpha, // 1
    q_device, q_rows_num,
    x, x_rows_num,
    &beta, // 0
    x_q_multiplication, q_rows_num);
```

where

```
dim = 3
x_rows_num = 4
q_rows_num = 2
```

would work but in that case I got error

```
** On entry to SGEMM  parameter number 8 had an illegal value
```

I also tried shuffling parameters a bit but I couldn't find any setup that would work.

So is it possible to multiply them without changing to column-major order?

**EDIT:**

So I got exepected results with changes made in this working example:

```
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

int main()
{
    int x_rows_num = 4;
    int q_rows_num = 2;
    int dim = 3;

int N = x_rows_num*dim;
int M = q_rows_num*dim;


float *x, *q, *x_q_multiplication;
cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
cudaMallocManaged(&q, M*sizeof(float));
cudaMallocManaged(&x_q_multiplication, q_rows_num*x_rows_num*dim);

for (int i = 0; i< N; i++) x[i] = i*1.0f;
for (int i = 0; i< M; i++) q[i] = (i + 3)*1.0f;

float *q_device;
cudaMallocManaged(&q_device, M*sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpy(q_device, q, M*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cublasHandle_t handle;
cublasCreate(&handle);

float alpha = 1.f;
float beta = 0.f;
cublasSgemm(handle,
    CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N,
    x_rows_num, q_rows_num, dim,
    &alpha, 
    x, dim, 
    q, dim,  
    &beta, 
    x_q_multiplication, x_rows_num);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

for (int i = 0; i < q_rows_num*x_rows_num; i++) std::cout << x_q_multiplication[i] << " ";

cudaFree(x);
cudaFree(q);
cudaFree(x_q_multiplication);
return 0;
}
```

However I'am still not sure why dim became leading dimension

Comment: `cublasSgemm(cublas_handle,
  CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N,
  q_rows_num, x_rows_num, dim,
  &alpha, 
  q_device, dim,  
  x, dim,
  &beta, 
  x_q_multiplication, q_rows_num);`

worked but I have no idea why, I thought that leading dim will always be the original number of rows.

Comment: @RobertCrovella regarding your first comment I enclosed example in original post with changes to leading dimension. Regarding your second comment I feel a little offended because as you could see in original example (cublasSgemm execution) I wanted to multiply q^t * x and with interpretation of cublas it would be 2x3 * 3x4 matrix multiplication but it seems that you stopped reading before it. I also thought that it is obvious that expected results would be just results of that multiplication in whatever order.

Answer (score 2):

Your original CUBLAS call:

```
cublasSgemm(cublas_handle,
    CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N,
    q_rows_num, x_rows_num, dim,
    &alpha, // 1
    q_device, q_rows_num,
    x, x_rows_num,
    &beta, // 0
    x_q_multiplication, q_rows_num);
```

was close to correct. Your interpretation of what the leading dimensions should be was correct. What you got wrong was the `Op` specifiers. If both matrices are row major ordered and the first  array needs to be read in its (row major) transposed order, then the operation should be:

```
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

int main()
{
    int x_rows_num = 4;
    int q_rows_num = 2;
    int dim = 3;

    int N = x_rows_num*dim;
    int M = q_rows_num*dim;

    float x0[12] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    float q0[6]  = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    float *x, *q, *x_q_multiplication;
    cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&q, M*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&x_q_multiplication, q_rows_num*x_rows_num*dim);

    std::memcpy(x, x0,  N*sizeof(float));
    std::memcpy(q, q0,  M*sizeof(float));

    float *q_device;
    cudaMallocManaged(&q_device, M*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(q_device, q, M*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    float alpha = 1.f;
    float beta = 0.f;
    cublasSgemm(handle,
            CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_T,
            q_rows_num, x_rows_num, dim,
            &alpha, // 1
            q_device, q_rows_num,
            x, x_rows_num,
            &beta, // 0
            x_q_multiplication, q_rows_num);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for (int i = 0; i < q_rows_num*x_rows_num; i++) std::cout << x_q_multiplication[i] << " "; std::cout << std::endl;

    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(q);
    cudaFree(x_q_multiplication);
    return 0;
}
```

which does this for me:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 cublas_trans.cu -o cublas_trans -lcublas 
$ ./cublas_trans 
76 88 91 106 106 124 121 142
```

and which I believe is the correct answer.

Incidentally, Robert Crovella's now deleted comment, which you say you take offense to was 100% correct. I suspect he read, as I did, your original CUBLAS call, interpreted the arguments and concluded, as I did, and as CUBLAS itself did, that you are trying to multiply a 3x4 matrix and a 3x2 matrix. Which is why the invalid argument error was raised.

Comment: I think expected result would be something like in this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B3,4,5%5D,%5B6,7,8%5D%5D*%5B%5B0,1,2%5D,%5B3,4,5%5D,%5B6,7,8%5D,%5B9,10,11%5D%5D%5ET)
and results like this I got in my enclosed main method.

Another thing maybe I got wrong, is that in your example I can see that you want to multiply Q*X. They common dimension is 3 so assuming that we have to interpret Q as transposition because of column/row major ordering so I think Q should be transposed to nullify ordering transform.

Comment: The alpha you linked to is not what is described in your question. What is described in your question is this: https://pastebin.com/LZhL0064